# I cannot get my PHP/XHTML page to fully load. I think it is a syntax error but I cannot find it

Tags: javascript, php, xhtml

My **Change Password Page** does not fully load. I have been searching for errors for hours. Only the `<html>` and `<body>` tags load. I removed the PHP inside the `<form>` and the page loads fine. I have been up and down all lines for hours. I also ran through a code checker, plus I use **Notepad++** so it also checks for errors. I did have this loading ealier just fine, but as I was making changes the problem occurred. Thanks for any help.

My file `change_pass.php` contains `XHTML`.

```
<?php include("pass.php") ; ?>//Session username and password.
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Change Password</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://website.com/connect.css"  />

<style type="text/css">

body {
   padding-top:50px;
}

input.frm {
   display:block;
   margin-top:15px;
}

table, input.frm {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}

td {
   padding:25px;
}

div.denyer_i {
   margin-right:0px;
}

#log_out_chpw {
   position:absolute;
   top:35px;
   right:20%;
}

</style>
</head>

<body class="change">

<a class="footer_hme" href="http://website.com"></a>
<a id="log_out_chpw" href="http://website.com/log_out.php">Log Out</a>
<br /><br /><br />

<form id="chpw_frm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ; ?>" method="post">

<?php
if ( isset($_SESSION["point"]) )//Username and password check
{
$user_sess = $_SESSION["username"] ;
$pass_sess = $_SESSION["pass"] ;
$usr = $_POST["usr"] ;
$old = $_POST["oldpass"] ;
$new = $_POST["newpass"] ;
$conf = $_POST["confpass"] ;

$usr_in = '<input id="usr_in" class="frm" type="text" name="usr" size="25" maxlength="30"  />' ;
$old_in = '<input id="old_in" class="frm" type="text" name="oldpass" size="25" maxlength="30"  />' ;
$new_in = '<input id="new_in" class="frm" type="text" name="newpass" size="25" maxlength="30"  />' ;
$conf_in = '<input id="conf_in" class="frm" type="text" name="confpass" size="25" maxlength="30"  />' ;

echo( ' <table><tr><td> ' ) ;
         echo( ' <h3>User Name</h3> ' ) ;
         echo( $usr_in ) ;
      echo( ' </td> ' ) ;

      echo( ' <td> ' ) ;
         echo( ' <h3>Old Password</h3> ' ) ;
         echo( $old_in ) ;
      echo( ' </td></tr> ' ) ;

   echo( ' <tr><td> ' ) ;
         echo( ' <h3>New Password</h3> ' ) ;
         echo( $new_in ) ;
      echo( ' </td> ' ) ;

      echo( ' <td> ' ) ;
         echo( ' <h3>Confirm Password</h3> ' ) ;
         echo( $conf_in ) ;
      echo( ' </td></tr> ' ) ;

   echo( ' <tr><td colspan="2"> ' ) ;

   if ( $old === $pass_sess && $usr === $user_sess )
      {
      if ( $new === $conf )
         {
         echo ( '
            <div style="color:#6f6bb6;">Your Password has been changed!</div>
            <br />
            ' ) ;
         }
      else
         {
         if ( $usr !== $user_sess )
            {
            echo ( '
               <div class="denyer_i">Incorrect User Name!</div>
               <br /><br />
               ' ) ;
            }
         if ( $new !== $conf )
            {
            echo ( '
               <div class="denyer_i">Your Confirmation Password does not match!</div>
               <br /><br />
               ' ) ;
            }
         }
      }
   else
      {
      echo ( '
         <div class="denyer_i">Incorrect!</div>
         <br /><br />
         ' ) ;
      }
   }
         echo ( ' <input class="log_sub" name="Sub" type="submit" value="Change Password"  /> ' ) ;
         echo ( ' <input class="log_sub" name="res" type="reset" value="Clear" style="margin-right:0px;"  /> ' ) ;
      echo ( ' </td></tr></table> ' ) ;
}
?>

</form>

<p class="cpy">2014-<?php echo date("Y") ; ?> website. All rights reserved.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

My `pass.php` file

```
<?php
session_start() ;
$_SESSION["username"] = "user" ;
$_SESSION["pass"] = "pass" ;
$_SESSION["point"] ;
?>
```

...also since the PHP requires to be logged in. A link from another page links to the **Change Password Page**.
`isset($_SESSION["point"])`

Comment: So, why is this tagged javascript again? Also what's in your pass.php? And try to make a .css for style.

Comment: Try delete the "   } " on line 121, just before " echo ( ' <input class="log_sub""

Comment: did you check your error log?

Comment: Also what's the point of the "pass.php" on line 135.

Comment: I am open to the use of javascript.

Comment: Checked error log. Also the point of the pass,php is to be used across many pages.

Comment: @Déjà vu I used CSS here because this page is unique and uses a lot of properties from a very large central CSS file. I try to always use a central file but this page required it.

Comment: I wish Notepadd++ would catch errors like this.

Comment: I did not take any tutorials or know how to make a change password feature so this is the Idea I came up with to be as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 extre close bracket after the 3 echoes, remove it

```
    $usr_in = '<input id="usr_in" class="frm" type="text" name="usr" size="25" maxlength="30"  />' ;
    $old_in = '<input id="old_in" class="frm" type="text" name="oldpass" size="25" maxlength="30"  />' ;
    $new_in = '<input id="new_in" class="frm" type="text" name="newpass" size="25" maxlength="30"  />' ;
    $conf_in = '<input id="conf_in" class="frm" type="text" name="confpass" size="25" maxlength="30"  />' ;

    echo( ' <table><tr><td> ' ) ;
    echo( ' <h3>User Name</h3> ' ) ;
    echo( $usr_in ) ;
    echo( ' </td> ' ) ;

    echo( ' <td> ' ) ;
    echo( ' <h3>Old Password</h3> ' ) ;
    echo( $old_in ) ;
    echo( ' </td></tr> ' ) ;

    echo( ' <tr><td> ' ) ;
    echo( ' <h3>New Password</h3> ' ) ;
    echo( $new_in ) ;
    echo( ' </td> ' ) ;

    echo( ' <td> ' ) ;
    echo( ' <h3>Confirm Password</h3> ' ) ;
    echo( $conf_in ) ;
    echo( ' </td></tr> ' ) ;

    echo( ' <tr><td colspan="2"> ' ) ;

    if ( $old === $pass_sess && $usr === $user_sess )
    {
        if ( $new === $conf )
        {
            echo ( '
                <div style="color:#6f6bb6;">Your Password has been changed!</div>
                <br />
                ' ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( $usr !== $user_sess )
            {
                echo ( '
                    <div class="denyer_i">Incorrect User Name!</div>
                    <br /><br />
                    ' ) ;
            }
            if ( $new !== $conf )
            {
                echo ( '
                    <div class="denyer_i">Your Confirmation Password does not match!</div>
                    <br /><br />
                    ' ) ;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo ( '
            <div class="denyer_i">Incorrect!</div>
            <br /><br />
            ' ) ;
    }
//}
    echo ( ' <input class="log_sub" name="Sub" type="submit" value="Change Password"  /> ' ) ;
    echo ( ' <input class="log_sub" name="res" type="reset" value="Clear" style="margin-right:0px;"  /> ' ) ;
    echo ( ' </td></tr></table> ' ) ;
}
?>
```

Comment: you got it! I knew it was something like that. But I spent waaay too much time looking. Woot! thanks everyone. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Is there a more minimal way to use the 'pass.php'?

Comment: ...Also the `===` and `!==` comparison operators created issues so I changed them to the `==` `!=` operators.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but... your error may be simply that you wrote

```
$user_sess = $_SESSION["userbame"] ;
```

instead of

```
$user_sess = $_SESSION["username"] ;
```

("userbame" instead of "username").

Comment: That was a typo in changing for this post.